# Передача параметров в ajax запросе

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Добрый день. Я хочу отправить значения из формы на сервер, записать их в базу и получить простой ответ.

```
index.php
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                              
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#but1").click(function(){
      $("#par1").load("add.php","user=ввввй&phone=5");
   })

});             
</script>                                                      
</head>
<body> 
<p id="par1">После нажатия на кнопку в данном поле будет отображен результат выполнения скрипта add.php.</p>
<input id="edit1" type="Edit" value="имя" />
<input id="edit2" type="Edit" value="телефон" />
<input id="but1" type="button" value="Передать данные скрипту" />
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    // подключаемся к серверу баз данных MySQL
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");

    // устанавливаем кодировку общения с MySQL
    $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $db->select_db("myDataBase111");

    $user = $_GET['user']; 
    $phone = $_GET['phone']; 
    echo "Имя: $name, Фамилия: $surname"; 
    $db->query("INSERT INTO phones (fio, phone) VALUES ('$user','$phone')");
?>
```

---

Эти данные отправляются и сохраняются. А вот как мне взять значения из `edit1/edit2` и передать их?
 Спасибо

Comment: делайте POST или .serialize()

Comment: Добавьте к Вашим input'ам атрибут name со значениями name и phone соответственно. После этого воспользуйтесь советом @eicto

Comment: Для начала хорошо бы эти инпуты в форму засунуть...

Comment: Смотрите какая магия

> $db->query("INSERT INTO phones (fio, phone) VALUES ('$user','$phone')");

Я - злой хакир. Я посылаю запрос, который разворачивается в следующую переменную:

    $user = 'fio\', \'+7 929 999 99 99\'); DROP TABLE phones; --'

И таблицы `phones` больше нет.

Comment: Спасибо )), я самый простой пример разбираю- потом с параметрами сделаю

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо большое. Разобрался.

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                              
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   


$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#but1").click(function(){
    $.post ('add1.php',{login:$("#edit1").val(),password:'password'},function(data,status){
        if( status=='success' ){
            eval('var obj='+data);
            if(obj.auth==true)
            {
                alert(obj.otvet);
            }
            else
                alert('Логин либо пароль не верны')
        }else{
            alert('В процессе отправки произошла ошибка :(')
        }
    })
   });
}); 


</script>                                                      
</head>
<body> 
<div id="div1">
</div>
<input id="edit1" type="Edit" value="Передать имя" />
<input id="but1" type="button" value="Передать данные скрипту" />
</body>
</html>


---------- add1.php
<?php
    if($_POST['login']=='1' and $_POST['password']=='password'){
        $auth = true;
        $User=$_POST['login'];
        $otvet = "Я принял твой запрос это $User";
       // setcookie('auth',md5($password.$login),time()+3600,'/');
    }else $auth = false;
    die( json_encode(array('auth'=>$auth,'otvet'=>$otvet)) );
?>
```